# Testrunner/framework for both .Net and Javascript?

Tags: .net, javascript, testing, automation, automated-tests

My team develops software using multiple languages.  We have a server app in .Net and much of our client code is written in JavaScript.  (The client code is actually for xulrunner applications, which don't have good testing tools right now, but I hope that is overcome someday.)

I like the idea, though, of having one testing tool that can run tests for all of our code.  Throwing out the xulrunner problem right now, and just **considering .net and Javascript - are there any options for testing and automation to cover both of these areas?**  Most of the popular testing tools I have seen seem to be .Net-focused.

Or **should I drop my desire to have one testing tool to rule them all, and simply choose the best of breed for each?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a single testing framework in a somewhat similar scenario - using NUnit to test both .Net and unmanaged C++ code. I just write the tests for the later in managed C++. This was nicer than using CppUnit IMO.

But in your case, there isn't a similar bridge between the .Net and JavaScript worlds that you could use. So you are likely better off using dedicated test frameworks for each platform.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into this post while doing a search on available JS TDD runners. There seems to be one for .NET, called JSTest.NET http://jstest.codeplex.com/ (please let me know if there are others). However, I've quite liked the JS-Test-driver http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/GettingStarted. It is something what I've in my mind: an automated javascript test runner that has an adapter for QUnit, targets multiple browsers, and can be used as part of the CI (what more can a guy ask for!)